# How i can extract substring from string using regular expression in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

I want to extract sub string from string using regular expression ie. the following input/out list shows what i really want. i need to extract the dept filter conditions from a string.
Here the word  **[dept]** is constant.so what the kind of regular expression is useful to extract the sub string in this scenario

```
    Input------------------------------------------------Output 

    Some conditions And [dept]=IT                        [dept]=IT
    Some conditions And [dept]=IT Or [dept]=Account      [dept]=IT Or [dept]=Account
    Some conditions And [dept] IN ('IT','Account')       [dept] IN ('IT','Account')

    [dept]=IT And some conditions                        [dept]=IT
    [dept]=IT Or [dept]=Account And some conditions      [dept]=IT Or [dept]=Account 
    [dept] IN ('IT','Account') And some conditions       [dept] IN ('IT','Account')
```

Comment: There are only these strings from where you want to fetch your o/p or there can be other combinations as well similar to your inputs

Comment: yes but the department values may change. these are the possible combinations, the structure of the string should be like this

Comment: It seems like you want everything after And in 1st 3 cases and everything before And in last3 cases, Is that what you want?

Comment: @jadavparesh06 yes sure

Comment: This looks a lot like extracting information from arbitrary SQL queries, and I'm 99.85% certain that this is not a task you should solve with a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be close to what you are after

```
(\[dept\]=\w+)( (Or)|(And))?|(\[dept\] IN \(.+?\))
```

It matches on your sample input like below, grouped in ().

```
([dept]=IT) 
([dept]=IT Or) ([dept]=Account) 
([dept] IN ('IT','Account'))
```

In your script you can join the groups on each line, ie., join `([dept]=IT Or) ([dept]=Account)`

But if like suggested in the comments you are indeed parsing SQL, there are SQL parsers that will give you accurate access to your query WHERE expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
\[dept\].*(?=\s+\bAnd\b)|\[dept\].*(?=$)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/41